# Qt: use ui pointer in separate function

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, scope, qt5

I would like to alter the GUI ui by using a separate function when an action takes place.

For example: here is my code for a menu item being clicked:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionImperial_triggered()
{
    ui->actionMetric->setChecked(false);
    ui->z_unit_label->setText("inches");
    void gui_change();
}
```

I would like the function `gui_change()` to be called, and alter the ui.

```
void gui_change()
{
    ui->pushButton_2->setStyleSheet("color:grey");
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("color:green");
}
```

This results in the error `use of undeclared identifier 'ui'`, being new to Qt, i have spent a few hours Googling and searching Stack to determine how to get `ui` to be within the scope of the function, but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make gui_change() a member function of MainWindow, and then declare it as `void MainWindow::gui_change()`.

If you simply write `void gui_change()`, then it is a standalone function that is not part of any class or namespace. (BTW, this is a C++ issue, not a Qt issue)

Comment: I tried making it a member function in `mainwindow.h` under `public:`, then `public slots:`, then `private:`, then `private slots:`, and these do allow the app to compile and run, but the function is not running. Any idea why that would be? If I move the code from within the function to the line where the function is being called, it runs fine.

Comment: @JimmyBanks But did you make it a member function in your `mainwindow.cpp`? Instead of declaring it as `void gui_change()`, declare it as `void MainWindow::gui_change()`. Also don't call it like this: `void gui_change();` in your `MainWindow::on_actionImperial_triggered()` function. Just call it like this: `gui_change();`.